# Rank Biserial Correlation with r

Tags: r

I have a non-normal distribution and two variables: one ordinal and the other a binary categorical, both from same sample population. I've found out that rank biserial correlations are the adequate to this kind of data.

Is there a package or can somebody help me to calculate a rank biserial correlation with p-value and effect size?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `polycor` package:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polycor/polycor.pdf
`polyserial()` might be what you are looking for

Comment: Is polyserial correlation non-parametric?

Comment: This is the description of polyserial correlation from the *polycor* package documentation.  It doesn't sound like this approach would be appropriate for the situation described in the question.  `Computes the polyserial correlation ... between a quantitative variable and an ordinal variable, based on the assumption that the joint distribution of the quantitative variable and a latent continuous variable underlying the ordinal variable is bivariate normal.`

Answer (score 1):

The command `wilcoxonRG` in the library `rcompanion` could help.

### Let's create a synthesis data for illustration:

```
library(rcompanion)
Criticism = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4)
Praise = c(4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 6)
Y = c(Criticism, Praise)
Bi_group = factor(c(rep("Criticism", length(Criticism)),  
                 rep("Praise", length(Praise))))
cbind(Y, Bi_group)
```

Then, this is the data that we created:

```
      Y Bi_group
 [1,] 1        1
 [2,] 1        1
 [3,] 0        1
 [4,] 0        1
 [5,] 2        1
 [6,] 2        1
 [7,] 2        1
 [8,] 3        1
 [9,] 4        1
[10,] 4        2
[11,] 4        2
[12,] 5        2
[13,] 5        2
[14,] 6        2
[15,] 6        2
[16,] 4        2
[17,] 3        2
[18,] 6        2
```

with Y is the ordinal and Bi_group is the binary categorical.

Then we can use the command

```
wilcoxonRG(x = Y, g = Bi_group, verbose=TRUE)
```

to get

```
Levels: Criticism Praise
n for Criticism = 9
n for Praise = 9
Mean of ranks for Criticism = 5.333333
Mean of ranks for Praise = 13.66667
Difference in mean of ranks = -8.333333
Total n = 18
2 * difference / total n = -0.926

    rg 
-0.926
```

### Note

You can also use the command

```
wilcoxonRG(table(Bi_group, Y))   #put the binary catergorical var first
```

to get

```
    rg 
-0.926
```

### References:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rcompanion/versions/2.4.1/topics/wilcoxonRG

Comment: An example of the Glass rank biserial correlation with the ToothGrowth data to compare to "*r*" statistic given in another answer: `data(ToothGrowth); rcompanion::wilcoxonRG(ToothGrowth$len, ToothGrowth$supp)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `rstatix::wilcox_test()` for *p* value and `rstatix::wilcox_effsize()` for effect size. The second function implements methods described in section "Effect size estimates used with non-parametric test" of article [1] on page 23. In the article, it is clearly explained how regular and squared versions of the coefficient should be interpreted.

Example (you are interested in `p` and `effsize`):

```r
rstatix::wilcox_test(len ~ supp, data = ToothGrowth)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic      p
#> * <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 len   OJ     VC        30    30      576. 0.0645


rstatix::wilcox_effsize(len ~ supp, data = ToothGrowth)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   .y.   group1 group2 effsize    n1    n2 magnitude
#> * <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <int> <int> <ord>    
#> 1 len   OJ     VC       0.240    30    30 small
```

References:

1. Tomczak M., Tomczak E. The need to report effect size estimates revisited. An overview of some recommended measures of effect size, Trends in Sport Sciences 21: 19–25 (2014). Available at: http://tss.awf.poznan.pl/files/3_Trends_Vol21_2014__no1_20.pdf.

Comment: This function doesn't produce the rank-biserial coefficient, but rather the "*r*" statistic.  My opinion on this "*r*" statistic: "This statistic has some drawbacks.  Under usual circumstances, it will not range all the way from –1 to 1.  It is also affected by sample size.  These problems appear to get worse when there are unequal sample sizes between the groups" (source: [rcompanion.org/handbook/F_04.html](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_04.html) ).